# Advaita vs Dvaita

Tags: advaita, vedanta, upanishads, dvaita, achintya-bheda-abheda

Which is really true Advaita or Dvaita as in Vedanta there are verses which agree with Dvaita philosophy and also verses which agree with Advaita philosophy. Many say that it depends on reality like there is physical reality, unseen realiy and absolute reality but Both Sri Adi Shankaracharya(avatar of Lord Shiva)and Sri Madhavacharya(avatar of Mukhyaprana Vayu) are considered as divine beings who studied Vedanta their entire life then how come they got different conclusions about the absolute truth

Comment: That really depends upon your goal. There have been really many spritual gurus in the past, select them and go upon their path. If you are interested in very high-fi techniques and fancy things - yoga, tantra, etc, then Advaita covers most of it. For regular spiritual practices - both of them cover it. Davita is not entirely Vedantic in the sense, that it needs to drag puranas to show things, while Advaita is pretty much logical and Vedanta inclined. If you wish to know more about Shatdarshanas - move towards Advaita.

Comment: Also please note Advaita is far older than Adi Shankaracharya. Usually, the guru of Raja Janak (BG 3.20 -21) is attributed to having created them during Ramayana itself - Yajnavalkya and Ashtavakra. So there are different varients of Advaita too, Adi Shankara's Advaita is just one of them.